# How to allow ElasticSearch to accept empty date fields?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I have a Python script that I use to load some data into ElasticSearch.

One of the fields I am loading is a `date` field, which on some rare occasions can be empty.

In my code, if there is no date, I assign it the string `"null"`:

```py
details["start_time"] = project_detail.get("start_time", "null")
```

In this case, I am getting the following error:

```py
***search.BadRequestError: BadRequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', "failed to parse field [start_time] of type [date] in document with id '1'. Preview of field's value: 'null'")
```

How can I make ES accept empty fields for this date field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"null"` (string) is not the same as `null`. ES will not be able to parse `"null"` as a date. You should probably just assign `None` instead so that the `date` field will just be missing.